# Perl Module errors while executing script

Tags: perl, unix

Here is the Perl script which will connect to SFTP server and pick some files. This script was set in Crontab under Unix server. I could see below errors when this script was executed.
Please suggest me what I need to do.

```
ERROR:
Can't locate Math/GMP.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SSH/Perl/Util/SSH1MP.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SSH/Perl/Util/SSH1MP.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SSH/Perl/Util.pm line 56.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SSH/Perl/Key/RSA1.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SSH/Perl/SSH1.pm line 13.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SSH/Perl/SSH1.pm line 13.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SSH/Perl.pm line 52.
```

SCRIPT:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use Net::SFTP;
use File::Copy;
use POSIX;

sub date_time()
{
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $day, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst) = localtime;
$mon = $mon+1;
$year = $year + 1900;
if (length($mon) == 1 ) { $nmon = "0$mon"; } else {$nmon = $mon; }
if (length($day) == 1 ) { $nday = "0$day"; } else {$nday = $day; }
if (length($hour)== 1 ) { $nhour = "0$hour"; }else {$nhour = $hour;}
if (length($min) == 1 ) { $nmin = "0$min"; } else {$nmin = $min; }
if (length($sec) == 1 ) { $nsec = "0$sec"; } else {$nsec = $sec; }

  return "$year-$nmon-$nday $nhour:$nmin:$nsec";
 }


 #open(LOG,">>/scripts/cons.Log") or print " Cant open log file \n";

 opendir(DIR,"/home/ftpcon/conin");
 #@files=grep{/.csv$/} readdir(DIR);
 @files= grep{!/^.$|^..$/}  readdir(DIR);
 closedir(DIR);

 if ( $sftp = Net::SFTP->new("xxxxxxxxx.net.au", user => "xxxxxx" , password => "xxxxxx") )  
{
#print " SFTP server connected  (".date_time().") \n"; 
}
else
{
print "SFTP server not connected  (".date_time().") \n";
}

foreach $file ( @files )
{
print " Started $file (".date_time().") \n";

my ($Psec, $Pmin, $Phour, $Pday, $Pmon, $Pyear, $Pwday, $Pyday, $Pisdst) = localtime();
$unixtime = mktime ($Psec, $Pmin, $Phour, $Pday, $Pmon, $Pyear, $Pwday, $Pyday, $Pisdst);
$Gtime = $unixtime + 25200 ;

my ($Gsec, $Gmin, $Ghour, $Gday, $Gmon, $Gyear, $Gwday, $Gyday, $Gisdst) = localtime($Gtime);
my $GTyear = 1900 + $Gyear;

if (length($Gmon) == 1 ) { $GTmon = "0$Gmon"; } else {$GTmon = $Gmon; }
if (length($Gday) == 1 ) { $GTday = "0$Gday"; } else {$GTday = $Gday; }
if (length($Ghour)== 1 ) { $GThour = "0$Ghour"; }else {$GThour = $Ghour;}
if (length($Gmin) == 1 ) { $GTmin = "0$Gmin"; } else {$GTmin = $Gmin; } 
if (length($Gsec) == 1 ) { $GTsec = "0$Gsec"; } else {$GTsec = $Gsec; } 

$Gdate = "$GTyear$GTmon$GTday"; 
$Gtime = "$GThour$GTmin$GTsec";


#($date,$time) = (split(/\_/,$file))[-2,-1];    
$originalfile = (split(/\./,$file))[0];
$Gfilename = $originalfile."_".$Gdate."_".$Gtime.".csv";
$originalfilename = $originalfile.".csv";
$filetransfered = 0;

print " $file renamed as $Gfilename for Processing  (".date_time().") \n"; 

###Connection to SFTP server

if ( $sftp->put("/home/ftpcon/conin/$file","/xxxxxxxx/yyy/$Gfilename") )
{
    print " $filename Copied to SFTP Server (".date_time().")\n";
    $filetransfered = 1;
}
else
{
    $mailfile = "mailretrieve.txt";
    open(MAIL,">$mailfile");
        print MAIL " $file Not Transfered ";
        close(MAIL);

        $cmd = "mailx -s \"File Not Transfered to SFTP Server\" xxxx\@goxxx.com < $mailfile";
    system($cmd);
    unlink("$mailfile");
            exit 1;
}

if ( $filetransfered )
{
    $source = "/home/ftpcon/conin/$file";
    $destination = "/home/ftpcon/coninbackup/$originalfilename"; 

    $success = copy($source,$destination); 

    if ( $success )
    {
    print " 1 .$filename copied from $source to $destination  (".date_time().") \n";
    }
    else
    {
        print " File Not transfered in coninbackup  \n";
    }


    $destination2 = "/home/ftpcon/coninbak/$originalfilename";

    $success = move($source,$destination2);
    if ( $success )
    {
    print " 2.$filename moved from $source to $destination2 (".date_time().") \n";
    }
    else
    {
        print " File Not Transfered in coninbak \n";
    }

    print "--------------------------------------------------------\n";
}
}
#close(LOG);

exit; 

#$sftp->ls("." , sub { print $_[0]->{longname}, "\n" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Math::GMP

Something like `cpan Math::GMP`

Comment: Hi Hamster & Kens... what about remaining lines in the error which I have shown. Are those lines also due to above module is missing?

Comment: Well, have you installed Math::GMP and are they still appearing?
They just telling you the link of the file that it is effecting

Comment: @Amareesh Why don't you just install Math::GMP and see for yourself? Also, if you want to notify someone whith a comment who is not the person under whose posts you comment, @ with their name is the way to go, as i just did with yours.

Comment: No Hamster. actually I need to raise a request to my Admin to install above module in server. Please confirm whether these errors are only due to the above module?? please let me know if I want to install any other modules, so that I can request my admin to install those modules in server.

Comment: Well that error that you mentioned above will dissappear when you install that module.

Comment: @DeVadder I'm not authorised to install by myself in the server. I need to raise a request as I mentioned above. Previously I haven't faced any issues like this. I need some clarification of what modules I need so that I can make a list and provide to my admin. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Net::SSH::Perl is quite hard to install. You may like to switch to Net::SFTP::Foreign (or Net::SFTP::Foreign::Compat) that has fewer dependencies (IIRC, just IO::Pty) and those are available as native packages for most Linux distributions.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

- You are missing modules that this script is calling.
- You are using Perl 5.8.8

Perl 5.8.8 is an old version of Perl. It was released in 2002 -- about 12 years ago. If you are on Solaris, you can upgrade to Perl 5.18 from [Sun Freeware](http://www.sunfreeware.com/introduction.html). I highly recommend you do this because starting with Perl 5.10, Perl started introducing a lot of nice new features and added more standard modules. For example, Perl 5.10 includes [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) which would replace much of the code you've shown with about 4 statements. Most of my Perl scripts now require at least Perl 5.10 in order to run.

The other problem is that you need to install `Math::GMP` and possibly `Net::SSH::Perl`.

Whenever you see the message `Can't locate ... in @INC`and then a bunch of directories that include the directories `perl` and `site`, you are missing a required module. I assume that you might need to install both, but there is a possibility that if you install `Math::GMP`, it will also install other dependent modules and that could include `Net::SSH::Perl` (although I doubt it).

You should also look into asking if you can use [Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl). Perlbrew allows you to install multiple *local* copies of Perl. This would allow you to add CPAN modules without going through the whole *Mother, May I?* routine with your IT department. However, although you can install Perlbrew without your IT department's blessing, I would not do it without their approval. You don't want to break corporate policy -- especially corporate policy that involves computers, unauthorized software, and the modification of system servers.

Comment: Thanks @David W for your suggestion. Will check with my admin regarding Perl version problem. And to confirm further please tell me is it mandatory that Perl version should be upgraded at this situation?
Or Installing the above Modules will solve my problem?
Any how will discuss regarding these 2 main points with my Admin.
But please suggest.

Comment: Installing the two modules will solve the immediate problem. However, Perl 5.10 started a great improvement in Perl itself and added dozens of extremely useful modules like `Time::Piece` which has become the standard way of handling time and date conversion. I highly recommend to upgrade to a more recent copy if at all possible.

Comment: Hi @David W really appreciate your way of explanation. For sure will request my admin to have Perl upgrade.

Comment: Hi @David W is the below modules are related to Math::GMP??
Math::BigInt::GMP and 
Math::BigInt::Pari

Comment: @Amareesh I'm not a big user of these modules, but here's my best effort to summarize them. `Math::BigInt` was the original. It uses Perl routines and libraries to handle big integers. `Math::GMP` is a replacement for `Math::BigInt`. It is _method compatible_, so replacing `Math::BigInt` with `Math::GMP` is easy to do. `Math::BigInt::GMP` uses the same Gimp library `Math::GMP` uses, but allows you to continue using `Math::BigInt` objects. As far as I understand, you don't `use` it. `Math::BigInt` will use `Math::BigInt::GMP` for you if it is installed.

Comment: @Amareesh In newer versions of Perl, you should use [`use bigint`](http://perldoc.perl.org/bigint.html) instead of one of the modules. `Math::BigInt::Calc` is used and include in Perl by default. However, you can specify Perl to use the GMP library via the pragma too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the perl module `Math::GMP` from CPAN.